# Krull dimension of a completion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

How does one study Krull dimension of some I-adic completion of a ring or, more generally, a module? I know that in case of Noetherian local ring Krull dimension of its completion equals Krull dimension of the ring, but what can we say in general case?

Comment: How general?  Are you concerned primarily about the local hypothesis, or do you also want something that works in the non-Noetherian case?

Comment: @Charles I'm mainly interested in Noetherian rings. If I'm not mistaken, Zariski rings also preserve Krull dimension under completion. Are there other well-behaved types of rings? Is it true for modules over Zariski ring? Or, maybe, there is a general technique to find it out...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a Noetherian ring R, the Krull dimension of its $I$-adic completion, $\hat{R}$ is given by $\sup h(J)$, where $J$ ranges over all maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and $h(J)$ is the [height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_(ring_theory)) of $J$. Therefore $\dim \hat R\le \dim R$ with equality only when $I\subset \operatorname{rad} R$. A reference is "Topics in $\mathfrak m$-adic topologies" by S.Greco, P.Salmon

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. This reasoning applies to modules as well, by the way.

Comment: What is an example of $I$ such that $I \not\subset {\mathrm{rad}}\,R$?